# Audio encode/decode on Android (ALAC, mp3...)

Tags: android, audio, decode, encode

I get a problem working with audio on Android (target version is Android 4.0). Audio files are encoded by different methods (most preferred of these: ALAC, AAC, MP3, OGG).
The problem lies in the following two points:

1.Need to re-encode the audio file of any format to ALAC.

2.Need to decode ALAC to PCM. Should be able to decode a certain number of packages, starting at certain package.

Maybe somebody knows some framework or libraries capable to solve these problems?

All of my research led me to the need of use ffmpeg libraries, but the use of the library generates a large number of problems, some of which proved unsolvable for me.